# To use or not to use SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, enterprise-wiki

Using SharePoint 2013.  Designing Wiki pages and soon to be creating workflows.  My understanding is Microsoft is phasing out Designer and InfoPath.

Is it worth using Designer, especially for Wiki's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not hesitate to use the designer, not a single day goes by where I don't use it during work (SharePoint consultant).

I don't see why you would be using it for wiki's though, but for workflows most definitely.

Comment: First 1/2 of your sentence says to hesitate, 2nd half says you use it every day.  I'm assuming you meant to say you would not hesitate to use it.

Comment: Hah sorry - missing a "not" :-D

Comment: Got Designer installed.  I see what you mean regarding Wiki pages in regards to Designer.  However, should work well designing Workflows.

Comment: it's working pretty well for workflows, we're using that a lot whereI work :)